# Is my GPA good enough for the graduate mathematics schools in the US?

Tags: graduate-admissions, mathematics, gpa

I am an undergraduate engineering student in Azerbaijan, and my major is process automation; however, I intend to change it and study mathematics in one of the grad schools in the US. I received only A's in mathematics classes, which are Calculus, Multivariable Calculus, Differential Equations, and Linear Algebra. Currently, I have been self-studying more advanced mathematics branches such as Real Analysis and Abstract Algebra, also have written a research paper on Differential Equations. Nevertheless, I have mediocre and low grades in the engineering classes such as "Electrical Materials and Devices", "Electrical Machines", "Process Control", etc. My current GPA is approximately 3.55, and I am planning to take GRE and GRE mathematics subject tests. Does my plan seem plausible? Am I eligible to study in PhD program for mathematics under such circumstances?

Comment: Your main problem is not GPA but lack of graded coursework in some standard upper division undergraduate classes. As it stands, you will not be competitive in the top 50 graduate programs in math in the US, unless you have done something spectacular in your differential equations paper.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is GRE math subject test effective considering the gap in my coursework? I will try to write a few more papers on Abstract Algebra though.

Comment: Could be but you would be competing with other international applicants who would have stellar GRE subject....

Comment: What do you mean "have written a research paper on Differential Equations"? Is this a research paper that got published in a peer-reviewed journal? Or?

Comment: Yes, do take the GRE mathematics subject test.  You will probably also need to show  English abilities, say TOEFL exam.

Comment: Yes, I have taken IELTS and got 8.0 out of 9.0 overall

Comment: The paper is published on the journal of an international conference.

Answer (score 1):

You can be considered, but note that doctoral admissions in US is broad based with letters of recommendation especially important. You are also missing some essential advanced courses that US undergrads usually take: Abstract Algebra and Topology for example. There are other common ones like Finite Math and Symbolic Logic.

There are some places that will let you make this up. But...

See this answer to our canonical question: [How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in Country X?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/176908/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-country-x/176909#176909)

Answer (score 0):

A GPA of 3.0 and above is usually the gold standard, at least in my field (physics), so it sounds like you are on the safe site. You may also consult with tools such as [this](https://www.scholaro.com/gpa-calculator/), which easily allows you to convert your non-US grades to a 4.0 system GPA.

Comment: 3.0 seems more like the silver standard, actually.

Comment: Totally agree, I meant that at least you make the cut

Comment: Thanks, the tool is quite helpful